# Removing style from selected text in edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

My app should allow users to style inputted or selected text in an Edittext. Some of these styles are Underline, Strike through, Bold and Italic. They are easily added but I don't know **how they could be removed** and **how I could determine if that style has already been added** to the selected text.
Code for adding style:

```
Spannable str = myEditText.getText();
    if (!SpannableUtils.isEmpty(str)) {
        str.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), startSelection, endSelection,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

I tried using removeSpan but it didn't work.
Also tried using

```
        str.setSpan(new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.DEFAULT),
                startSelection, endSelection,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

but it poses the error : The constructor StyleSpan(Typeface) is undefined.

Comment: sorry. updated the question with the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this class solve your problem.

```
public class StyleSpanRemover {

    public void RemoveOne(Spannable spannable,
                          int startSelection, int endSelection, Class<?> style){

        ArrayList<SpanParts> spansParts = getSpanParts(spannable, startSelection, endSelection);
        removeOneSpan(spannable, startSelection, endSelection, style);
        restoreSpans(spannable, spansParts);
    }

    public void RemoveStyle(Spannable spannable,
              int startSelection, int endSelection, int styleToRemove){

        ArrayList<SpanParts> spansParts = getSpanParts(spannable, startSelection, endSelection);
        removeStyleSpan(spannable, startSelection, endSelection, styleToRemove);
        restoreSpans(spannable, spansParts);
    }

    public void RemoveAll(Spannable spannable, int startSelection, int endSelection){

        ArrayList<SpanParts> spansParts = getSpanParts(spannable, startSelection, endSelection);
        removeAllSpans(spannable, startSelection, endSelection);
        restoreSpans(spannable, spansParts);
    }

    protected void restoreSpans(Spannable spannable, ArrayList<SpanParts> spansParts){

        for (SpanParts spanParts : spansParts) {
            if(spanParts.part1.canAplly())
                spannable.setSpan(spanParts.part1.span, spanParts.part1.start,
                                  spanParts.part1.end,spanParts.span_flag);
            if(spanParts.part2.canAplly())
                spannable.setSpan(spanParts.part2.span, spanParts.part2.start,
                                  spanParts.part2.end, spanParts.span_flag);
        }
    }

    protected void removeAllSpans(Spannable spannable,int startSelection, int endSelection) {

        Object spansToRemove[] = spannable.getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, Object.class);
        for(Object span: spansToRemove){
            if(span instanceof CharacterStyle)
                spannable.removeSpan(span);
        }
    }

    protected void removeOneSpan(Spannable spannable,int startSelection, int endSelection,
                           Class<?> style) {

        CharacterStyle spansToRemove[] = spannable.getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, CharacterStyle.class);
        for(CharacterStyle span: spansToRemove){
            if(span.getUnderlying().getClass() == style )
                spannable.removeSpan(span);
        }
    }

    protected void removeStyleSpan(Spannable spannable, int startSelection,
        int endSelection, int styleToRemove) {

        MetricAffectingSpan spans[] = spannable.getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, MetricAffectingSpan.class);
        for(MetricAffectingSpan span: spans){
            int stylesApplied = 0;  
            int stylesToApply;
            int spanStart;
            int spanEnd;
            int spanFlag;
            Object spanUnd = span.getUnderlying();
            if(spanUnd instanceof StyleSpan){
                spanFlag = spannable.getSpanFlags(spanUnd);
                stylesApplied = ((StyleSpan) spanUnd).getStyle();
                stylesToApply = stylesApplied & ~styleToRemove;

                spanStart = spannable.getSpanStart(span);
                spanEnd = spannable.getSpanEnd(span);
                if(spanEnd >= 0 && spanStart >= 0){
                    spannable.removeSpan(span);
                    spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(stylesToApply), spanStart, spanEnd,spanFlag);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected ArrayList<SpanParts> getSpanParts(Spannable spannable,
                                              int startSelection,int endSelection){

        ArrayList<SpanParts> spansParts = new ArrayList<SpanParts>();
        Object spans[] = spannable.getSpans(startSelection, endSelection, Object.class);
        for(Object span: spans){
            if(span instanceof CharacterStyle){
                SpanParts spanParts = new SpanParts();
                int spanStart = spannable.getSpanStart(span);
                int spanEnd = spannable.getSpanEnd(span);
                if(spanStart == startSelection && spanEnd == endSelection) continue;
                spanParts.span_flag = spannable.getSpanFlags(span);
                spanParts.part1.span = CharacterStyle.wrap((CharacterStyle) span);
                spanParts.part1.start = spanStart;
                spanParts.part1.end = startSelection;
                spanParts.part2.span = CharacterStyle.wrap((CharacterStyle) span);
                spanParts.part2.start = endSelection;
                spanParts.part2.end = spanEnd;
                spansParts.add(spanParts);
            }
        }
        return spansParts;
    }

    private class SpanParts{
        int span_flag;
        Part part1;
        Part part2;
        SpanParts() {
            part1 = new Part();
            part2 = new Part();
        }
    }
    private class Part{
        CharacterStyle span;
        int start;
        int end;
        boolean canAplly() {
            return start < end;
        }
    }
}
```

**How to use:**

```
int startSelection=editText.getSelectionStart();
int endSelection=editText.getSelectionEnd();
Spannable spannable = editText.getText();

StyleSpanRemover spanRemover = new StyleSpanRemover();
// to remove all styles
spanRemover.RemoveAll(spannable,startSelection,endSelection);
//to remove only StrikethroughSpan style use:
spanRemover.RemoveOne(spannable,startSelection,endSelection,StrikethroughSpan.class);
//to remove one StyleSpan use:
spanRemover.RemoveStyle(spannable,startSelection,endSelection,Typeface.BOLD)
```

Comment: Spannable still has those methods.. But they don't do the trick when I use it with removeSpan.

Comment: Yes is true since both implements Spanned. I need more information in order to help because `removeSpan` should work

Comment: remove span does work, but now the way i want it to. My goal is to remove the style pan only from the selected text. not the entire text in the edittext.

Comment: The problem is when, for example, a style is applied to four characters and you select two inner to remove the style, the initial style must be splitted in two. To handle that I will update my answer.

Comment: It works only at the first time a substring is selected.. :| But modified it and got it to work for another problem (removing only of a specific style eg. bold then italic are added then either should be removed) thanks

Comment: Have you tried the latest changes? Any comments would be appreciated

Comment: If my string is both bold and italics and i just want that bold style should be removed, what should i do in that case ?

Comment: @Rahul Gupta - I update my answer to add support for StyleSpan and  resolve some issues.

Comment: I have used your code, but i have a problem. I have posted my problem here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307409/remove-style-on-spans

Answer (score 3):

`android.graphics.TYPEFACE.Default` returns a `Typeface`, and the `StyleSpan` constructor takes an `int` as paramater.

Try using :

```
android.graphics.Typeface.DEFAULT.getStyle()
```

instead of:

```
android.graphics.Typeface.DEFAULT
```

Comment: android.graphics.Typeface.DEFAULT.getStyle() didn't do the trick. It revert the text to its original style.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way below is the simplest but useful. It works for me.

Please try this code:

```
myEditText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
```